# How to use javascript in eclipse-android to build an android testing program?

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, monkeyrunner

How to use javascript in eclipse-android to build an android testing program?
I have no idea to test, just have learned android application developments.
someone use Python to do,I just want to have a try to use javascript, may be something about monkeyrunner. 
The perticular,the better!
thanks verymuch!

Comment: Have you tried or searched around for anything?

Comment: may be python would be easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have had the same scenario and i din't fount any javascript dependency in android either
so what i did was , i made some base validation class , took the fields one by one and validated the form with object of the base class one by one , then only submitted the form , its all very simple , if u r having a real hard time finding some solution and lack of time , i would suggest you do the same .